# Jquery Form Validation Posição do div de erro em campos select

Tags: jquery, posicionamento, jquery-select2

Como mudar a posição do texto de erro em campos select2. está aparecendo em cima do campo, quero que aparece abaixo! Alguma dica?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<!-- /field -->
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">SEXO
<span class="required"> * </span>
</label>

<select name="sexo" id="sexo" class="form-control select2" tabindex="9" required>

<? 
if($Obj->sexo=="F") $sexo = "Feminino"; 
if($Obj->sexo=="M") $sexo = "Masculino";
?>

<optgroup label="">
<option value="<?=$Obj->sexo?>" selected > <?=$sexo?> </option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="...">
<option value="F">Feminino  </option>       
<option value="M">Masculino </option>       
</optgroup>
</select>

</div>
</div>
<!-- /field -->



<!-- field -->
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">NOME COMPLETO
<span class="required"> * </span>
</label>

<div class="input-icon right"><i class="fa"></i>
<input type="text" autofocus onfocus="select(this);" id="nomecompleto" name="nomecompleto" minlength="3" maxlength="150" class="form-control jump" 
    value="<?=htmlspecialchars($Obj->nomecompleto)?>" required tabindex="2">
</div></div>
</div>
<!-- /field -->
```

Comment: Adicione a pergunta o código usado para o podermos ajudar

Comment: Acredito ser um erro super simples.. vá no seu código html no input referente ao sexo. copie a tag acima dele e passe para baixo dele, deve resolver.

Comment: Coloque também o html do campo nome completo, para compararmos com o do sexo e ver a posição das tags em cada um.

Comment: O código é apenas para inerir um asterisco! Náo surgiu efeito nenhum, continua o mesmo problema. Acredito que deva ser alguma coisa dentro do jquery do form validation... mas náo sei aonde.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui Resolver.

Dentro do arquivo js que tem a função do form validation tem a opção de `errorplacement`, então foi só criar o elemento após achar o elemento com a classe desejada. Funcionou 100%.

```
if (element.parent(".form-group").size() > 0) {
  error.insertAfter(element.next('.select2'));
}
```